# Generate new Session ID for JSESSIONID in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, jsessionid

Our main application is built on Asp.Net MVC. We have another service (or subsystem) developed in Java for Login Authentication. So our application has two Session Variables.

- ASP.NET_SessionId (Generated by our main MVC application)
- JSESSIONID (Generated by the java subsystem)

We have to provide new session ids for sessions once the user has logged in. Its a requirement to prevent session fixation. I can generate a new session id for the ASP.NET_SessionId using the below code.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("JSESSIONID", ""));
```

The above code generates a new session id for ASP.NET_SessionId. But for "JSESSIONID" its clearing the session id value and it's being blank.

Please help me to create a new session id for JSESSIONID in Asp.net application.

Comment: Anyone could help me on the above please? Its killing my time...:(

Comment: Still no suggestion on this???

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to generate the jsessionid from .NET?